# No conversion value provided for the attribute [CO]

Tags: jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I have an xsd which conatins a entity Taddress having a property country_code which has enum type. I am uanble to marshal the xml out of the root entity because it throws an exception as below

> javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
>    - with linked exception: [Exception [EclipseLink-25003] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b):
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException Exception
>   Description: An error occurred marshalling the object Internal
>   Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-115] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
>   2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException Exception
>   Description: No conversion value provided for the attribute [CO].
>   Mapping:
>   org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLDirectMapping[countryCode-->country_code/text()]
>   Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(generated.TAddress --> [])]     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller.marshal(JAXBMarshaller.java:403)
>     at
>   com.crrinfra.dynamicOutputgen.utils.HelloWorld.generateTransaction(HelloWorld.java:52)
>     at
>   com.crrinfra.dynamicOutputgen.utils.XMLUtilities.generateJaxBContext(XMLUtilities.java:259)
>     at
>   com.crrinfra.dynamicOutputgen.utils.DynamicXSDLoader.populateCache(DynamicXSDLoader.java:48)
>     at
>   com..crrinfra.dynamicOutputgen.DynamicOutputXSDParser.main(DynamicOutputXSDParser.java:16)
>   Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-25003] (Eclipse Persistence Services
>   - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException Exception
>   Description: An error occurred marshalling the object Internal
>   Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-115] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
>   2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException Exception
>   Description: No conversion value provided for the attribute [CO].
>   Mapping:
>   org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLDirectMapping[countryCode-->country_code/text()]
>   Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(generated.TAddress --> [])  at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException.marshalException(XMLMarshalException.java:97)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLMarshaller.marshal(XMLMarshaller.java:911)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLMarshaller.marshal(XMLMarshaller.java:848)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller.marshal(JAXBMarshaller.java:401)
>     ... 4 more

public class HelloWorld {

```
public static void generateTransaction(DynamicJAXBContext jaxbContext) throws JAXBException, NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException{
    DynamicEntity entity = jaxbContext.newDynamicEntity("generated.Report");
    DynamicType type = jaxbContext.getDynamicType("generated.Report");

    DynamicEntity childEntity3 = jaxbContext.newDynamicEntity("generated.TAddress");
    DynamicType type1 = jaxbContext.getDynamicType("generated.TAddress");
    childEntity3.set("addressType", "M");
    childEntity3.set("address", "XXXX");
    childEntity3.set("town", "XXX");
    childEntity3.set("city", "XXXXX");
    childEntity3.set("zip", "751006");
    childEntity3.set("countryCode", "CO");
    childEntity3.set("state", "OD");
    childEntity3.set("comments", "Permanent Address");
    entity.set("location", childEntity3);

    XMLDirectMapping enumMappings = (XMLDirectMapping) ((DynamicTypeImpl) type1).getMapping("countryCode");
    System.out.println(enumMappings.isDirectToFieldMapping());
    JAXBMarshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.marshal(entity, System.out);
}
```

}

Please advise on how to set the property. I have uploaded the xsd with this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to my question and hence thought of closing this thread. I would be happy to receive feedback on this approach

```
public class EnumAttributeHandler implements IAttributeHandler {    
DynamicTypeImpl typeAttr;
public EnumAttributeHandler(DynamicTypeImpl typeAttr) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.typeAttr=typeAttr;
}
@Override
public DynamicEntity attributeSetter(CRROutputAttributePojo attrPojo, DynamicEntity currentEntitytag, HashMap<String, Object> params,String setterValue) throws CRROutputGenException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    XMLDirectMapping enumMappings = (XMLDirectMapping) (typeAttr)
            .getMapping(attrPojo.getActualAttrName());
    EnumTypeConverter converter=null;
    if(enumMappings.getConverter() instanceof EnumTypeConverter)
        converter = (EnumTypeConverter) enumMappings.getConverter();
    else 
        throw new CRROutputGenException("Invalid type of converter");
    try {
        if (setterValue != null) {
            Object enumField = ((DynamicJAXBContext) params.get("jaxbContext")).getEnumConstant(converter.getEnumClassName().toString(), setterValue);
            currentEntitytag.set(attrPojo.getActualAttrName(), enumField);
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new CRROutputGenException(e.getMessage());
    }
return  currentEntitytag;
}
}
```